# C - pthread segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm creating a thread and passing a pointer to it.
But when I cast this pointer to be as it should be back an (int*) I have a segmentation fault.

```
int *ptr = (int *)ptrTotal2;
```

Here is the code :

```
void *firstCalc(void *ptrTotal2){
  int valA = 1;
  int valB = 2;
  int *ptr = (int *)ptrTotal2;
  *ptr = valA + valB;
  printf("Value of valA = %d\nValue of valB = %d\n", valA, valB);
  printf("Value of subtotal *ptrTotal1 = %d\n", *ptr);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  pthread_t thread1;
  int *ptrTotal2 = 0;
  int iret1;

  iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, firstCalc, (void*) ptrTotal2); 
  if(iret1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  pthread_join( thread1, NULL);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing `ptr` in the function `firstCalc`, when the original pointer was set to 0, will cause undefined behavior, in your case a segmentation fault.

```
int *ptr = (int *)ptrTotal2;
*ptr = valA + valB;
...
int *ptrTotal2 = 0;
```

Instead allocate memory for an integer, and pass it to the created thread, and free it after the thread ends:

```
int *ptrTotal2 = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
if( !ptrTotal2 )
{
    abort();
}

//... call pthread_create, pthread_join

free( ptrTotal2 );
```

Note, that you have to use allocated memory (use malloc), because reading an automatic variable from a different thread is implementation defined.

> 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects
>
> 5. The
>    result of attempting to indirectly access an object with automatic storage duration from a
>    thread other than the one with which the object is associated is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks it help a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You ara dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, that causes the segmentation fault because it's undefined behavior.

Try this

```
int value = 0;
int *ptrTotal2 = &value;
```

and please keep the `pthread_join(thread1, NULL);` or `value` will be deallocated and again *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 0):

You did not get the segmentation fault while *assigning* the pointer, you got it because you tried dereferencing the pointer, which is NULL, at a later point.

In your `main()`, you've written

```
 int *ptrTotal2 = 0;
```

which is *basically* the same as

```
 int *ptrTotal2 = NULL;
```

Now, inside the thread function, you're doing

```
 *ptr = valA + valB;
```

which is an attempt to dereference a NULL pointer. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB.

What you can try doing is

- make `ptrTotal2` an `int`, like `int ptrTotal2 = 0`;
- pass the address of it, like `iret1 = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, firstCalc, &ptrTotal2);`

Comment: umm. what's the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `printf` the value of the `ptr` pointer. It's a `NULL` pointer because the `ptrTotal2` is also a `NULL` pointer there. Then in the following expression

```
*ptr = valA + valB;
```

the `*ptr` is trying to dereference from the address which `ptr` pointed, unfortunately the `ptr` point to NULL, So the segment fault occurred.